# SQL Server Always Encrypted Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(60) when running EXEC sproc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, operand, always-encrypted

I am unable to EXEC a stored procedure that upserts a table that has an encrypted column using Always Encrypted. However, I am able to copy the SQL from the sproc and run that as regular SQL with the parameters set, **Just cannot get the sproc to fire when executing the sproc via the EXEC function in SSMS which is also causing problems in the application**

The table has a trigger on it that inserts into another audit table of similar structure that is also encrypted using the same encryption. I have done the usual thing:

Checking the Enable Parameterizaion for Always Encrypted in Query Options

Setting column encryption setting=enabled on the Connection Settings.

Refreshing the encyrption metadata for the sproc:

```
    EXEC sp_refresh_parameter_encryption 'organization.uspOrganizationAddressUpsert'
```

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE [organization].[OrganizationAddress](
[OrganizationAddressId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CreatedUser] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateUser] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[RemovedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[Address1] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[Address2] [varchar](60) NULL,
[City] [varchar](60) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
[State] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[ZipCode] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[ClientNumberId] [int] NOT NULL

    CREATE TABLE [audit].[OrganizationAddressAudit](
[OrganizationAddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedUser] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateUser] [int] NOT NULL,
[LastUpdateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[RemovedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[Address1] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[Address2] [varchar](60) NULL,
[City] [varchar](60) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL,
[State] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[ZipCode] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
[ClientNumberId] [int] NOT NULL,
[OperationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Operation] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[OperationBy] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
```

Stored Procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [organization].[uspOrganizationAddressUpsert]
    @OrganizationId INT,
    @ExecutingUserId INT,
    @Address1 VARCHAR(60),
    @Address2 VARCHAR(60),
    @City VARCHAR(60),
    @State VARCHAR(60),
    @ZipCode VARCHAR(60),
    @ClientNumberId INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @RightNow AS DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME()
    If EXISTS (Select 1 From [organization].[OrganizationAddress] Where ClientNumberId = @ClientNumberId)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [organization].[OrganizationAddress] SET
            LastUpdateUser = @ExecutingUserId,
            LastUpdateDate = @RightNow,
            Address1 = @Address1,
            Address2 = @Address2,
            City = @City,
            [State] = @State,
            ZipCode = @ZipCode,
            RemovedDate = Null
            Where ClientNumberId = @ClientNumberId
            END
    ELSE
        BEGIN -- INSERT part of the UPSERT
            INSERT INTO [organization].[OrganizationAddress]
            (CreatedUser
            ,CreatedDate
            ,LastUpdateUser
            ,LastUpdateDate
            ,Address1
            ,Address2
            ,City
            ,[State]
            ,ZipCode
            ,ClientNumberId)
            VALUES
            (@ExecutingUserId
            ,@RightNow
            ,@ExecutingUserId
            ,@RightNow
            ,@Address1
            ,@Address2
            ,@City
            ,@State
            ,@ZipCode
            ,@ClientNumberId)   
        END
END
```

Running the stored procedure code with the paramteers set is fine, but I am unable to EXEC the sproc:

```
        declare @orgId INT = 1;
declare @client int = 888;
declare @user int = 1;
declare @Add1 varchar(60)= 'Test Address1';
declare @Add2 varchar(60)= 'Test Address2';
declare @city varchar(60) = 'City';
declare @state varchar(60) = 'St';
declare @zip varchar(60) = '12345';

EXEC organization.uspOrganizationAddressUpsert 
    @OrganizationID=@orgID,
    @ExecutingUserId = @user, -- int
    @Address1 = @Add1, -- varchar(60)
    @Address2 = @Add2, -- varchar(60)
    @City = @city, -- varchar(60)
    @State = @state, -- varchar(60)
    @ZipCode = @zip, -- varchar(60)
    @ClientNumberId = @client; -- int

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure uspOrganizationAddressUpsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 1]
Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(60) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'BankruptcyApp') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

I created a similar table in a test DB with VARCHAR(60) for the enrcrypted columns, a trigger, and an audit table and its working fine there and I cant find any differences in the table/sproc/trigger that would allow it to work there and not here. I've pretty much exhausted the other posts and blogs I can find.

Comment: The error states a varchar collation that's not compatible with Encryption (i.e not BIN) wonder if it happens with NVARCHAR as well

Comment: I thought about that, but its working in a test db where the columns are also VARCHAR.

Comment: This working on some DB might imply this is a configuration issue, what the default collation on your test db?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Needed to update the app code to specify the data type and length:

```
parameters.Add("@City", organizationAddress.City, System.Data.DbType.AnsiString, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 60);
```

where it was previously just:

```
parameters.Add("@City", organizationAddress.City)
```

This at least get the app to run the sproc but still cant run it from SSMS via EXEC